# ViewModel does not update Combobox SelectedValue

Tags: wpf, vb.net, mvvm, combobox, vsix

I've got a problem with a Combobox in a VSIX-Project. I'm using the MVVM-pattern.

```
<ComboBox
            ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name"
           IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
            Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}"
            SelectedValue="{Binding Project, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

This is my Combobox which is bindet to a List of Projects. The SelectedValue is a project of the list. Like this:

```
ProjectList = New List(Of Project)(Helper.GetFormsProjects())
  If ProjectList.Count > 0 Then
     Project = ProjectList(0)
  End If
```

But if I select another Value in the Combobox, it wouldn't call the setter of the project property.

Here are the properties:

```
   Public Property _projectList As List(Of Project)
   Public Property ProjectList As List(Of Project)
      Get
         Return _projectList
      End Get
      Set(value As List(Of Project))
         _projectList = value
         OnPropertyChanged()
      End Set
   End Property

   Public Property _project As Project
   Public Property Project As Project
          Get
             Return _project
          End Get
          Set(value As Project)
             _project = value
             OnPropertyChanged()
          End Set
       End Property
```

Comment: Besides that setting `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is redundant, you should bind `SelectedItem` instead of `SelectedValue`. Note also that on the ItemsSource binding, setting `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is pointless. It has no effect at all.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with Mode and UpdateSourceTrigger.
I already tried SelectedItem, it doesn't call the setter too.

Comment: Is there a Project selected initially?

Comment: I set the project to the first project in the list, you can see it in the second code-block i posted in my question.
But before that, there is no project initialized.

Comment: What if you bind to SelectedItem and remove IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem=true?

Comment: IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem is redundant as well.

Comment: If all the above did not help, have a look at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.diagnostics.presentationtracesources.tracelevel.aspx  This will give you a lot of additional console output that should help to track the issue.

Comment: Collections should be read only properties, and you should be using ObservableCollections. When binding to a combo box, the object bound to SelectedItem **must be found within the collection bound to ItemsSource**. If you're juggling instances (to/from a database, some serialized form, etc) you have to make sure to keep the collection in sync with SelectedItem.

Comment: There is still no solution that works for me, i tried every point you all  made. @Will the SelectedItem is sync with the List, as you can see in the second code block. I also tried a ObservableCollection and it doesnt work for me too.

Comment: I know it's not in (ugh) vb, but here's an example of how it works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47696868/wpf-sorting-an-observablecollection-de-selects-a-combobox/47697935#47697935 you can convert that to vb and execute it to see that it does. Compare it to your application. What are you doing differently? Alter the given example in increments so that it more closely matches your application. At some point it will break, and you will know what you're doing wrong. Good luck.